# Layout VS Layout update

Tags: magento-1.7, layout, xml

When I started to learn abot XML Layout in magento, I come to know two terms namely **Layout** and **Layout Update**.

Definition for these two terms in an article was

**The term layout refers to the visual and structural composition of the page. However, the term layout update refers to a specific set of XML instructions that determines how the page is constructed.**

But I'm not able to understand it with xml files of magento.

Can anyone explain these two terms with an example xml file of magento?

Answer (score 1):

`<catalog_product_compare_index translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Product Compare List</label>
    <!-- Mage_Catalog -->
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/popup.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/scriptaculous.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>varien/product.js</script></action>
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>head.viewport</name></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/product_compare_list" name="catalog.compare.list" template="catalog/product/compare/list.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_compare_index>`

Inside `catalog_product_compare_index` XML rule we have layout rules that components the **Layout Update**. 
By **Layout** we mean the XML structure, with **Layout Update** we mean all the updates we do using the XML structure.

By using a handle such as `catalog_product_compare_index`, we update only a specific page. By using the `default` handle, we update the overall Layout structure of our site.

Hoped i helped you, cause this will mean that i understated as well. :)

Read more [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/intro-to-layouts)

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation, I could understand layout update, but what's that "xml structure".